# finding specific values from file using java

Tags: java, file-handling

I have JSP file with some code

```
<div id="ListDiv" **class="ListDiv"** style="overflow: auto; visibility: visible">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table **class="List"** cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="ColHeader"><%=I18N.get("KEY_LABEL_Sr_No", w_locTextObj)%>.</td>
                        <td class="ColHeader"><%=I18N.get("KEY_LABEL_Project", w_locTextObj)%></td>
                        <td class="ColHeader"><%=I18N.get("KEY_LABEL_Status", w_locTextObj)%></td>
                        <td class="ColHeader"><%=I18N.get("KEY_LABEL_Estimated_Hours", w_locTextObj)%></td>


...
```

like this i wanted to find "class=" string and want value of it `"ListDiv" (class="ListDiv",class="List")` how many time means there count with value of class how can i get it .

1. I have to read file using java
2. finding out "class=" string but how can i get value?

Comment: `class=` is inside every tag. It is the **attribute** of the tags **td** for example.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open and read the file. I assume you can do that. Note that your JSP and the generated HTML might have different counts for those values, e.g. when iterating over some collection.

2) In that case you might try and use a regular expression like `class="([^"]*)"` which would return anything after the string `class="` and before the next double quotes as group 1. Note that in Java strings you have to escape the double quotes in that expression.

Example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("class=\"([^\"]*)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourFileContent);

while( m.find() ) {
  String classValue = m.group( 1 );
  //do whatever you want
}
```